# How Can I Convert a Column of M/D/Y, Time to Y/M/D, Time in a MYSQL Table?

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I saw some other questions like mine but not exactly like mine.  I have a column in one of my tables called `time`, but since the new year, when I order by `time`, it's not pulling in the correct chronological order because the year isn't being factored into the ordering.  It's basically ordering by month/day.

So, I am assuming there is a command I could execute that would convert the `time` column, which is currently `M/D/Y, hour:minutes:seconds`, to a `Y/M/D, hour:minutes:seconds`.

I just have no clue what it is.

Comment: Is your `time` column of type DATETIME or is it a string?

Comment: and is the year format a double decimal, or quad-decimal ? Eg. 12 or 2012 ? Does this matter into the result you want to get (assumingly you want the same)?

Comment: Please give specific example of the exact date formats you currently have.

Comment: It's a string.  Here's an example: 10/12/12,23:37:50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should make this column a datetime column so that don't run into problem like this, but since you can't do that until you sanitize the data. We will make the conversion for you here.  First add a new datetime field

First populate the date from the m/d/Y records:

```
UPDATE table SET new_datetime= STR_TO_DATE(old_datetime, '%m/%d/%y,%H:%i:%s') WHERE autoincrement <= [Last autoincrement value for m/d/y format];
```

Then populate from the Y/m/d records:

```
UPDATE table SET new_datetime= STR_TO_DATE(old_datetime, '%y/%m/%d,%H:%i:%s') WHERE autoincrement > [Last autoincrement value for m/d/y format];
```

You can then delete your old field.

Please note that you need to make sure the format used in the `STR_TO_DATE()` function matches what you currently have (for example I wasn't sure is you had a literal `,` in your string or had all 2 digits months/days. You may need to adjust the format pattern accordingly.  See this link for information on how to specify the format http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: I believe this will work, but it's setting the new datetime column as all zeros.  I must be doing something wrong..

Comment: Just noted your updated comment with actual string format. You will definitely need to add a comma into the string format (I have updated my answer).  You will however have a problem in that you have 2 digit years.  My method trying to look for `__/` (for month first) or `____/` (for year first will not work).  Do you have any way to know exactly which records are in which order (i.e is there an autoincrement field where you know all values above X start using the y/m/d format instead of m/d/y?  Without such a value you might have ambiguous dates.

Comment: @user1799250 Great, that will make things easy (assuming you can identify where the last autoincrement in the m/d/y format is).  Please see updated queries in answer.

Comment: It worked.  I appreciate this a lot.  I'm new a this.  Forgive me.  How would I insert that new time format into the table.  What is the easiest method to use ?  I guess i would just use this: %y/%m/%d,%H:%i:%s ?

Comment: I tried a test inserting it into the table with strftime('%y/%m/%d,%H:%i:%s') but it left out the minutes and seconds.. hm..

Comment: MySQL format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, so you would need to use that format (You could also specify `YYYY-MM-DD` and MySQL would add 00:00:00 for time component).  If this is a timestamp field, the easiest way to insert the data is using `NOW()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. You can also set up the field to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value if you don;t want to both with the date on the insert.  Finally, you an have a single timestamp field on a table which also updates itself automatically on updates to the row, there are some caveats to doing this, so definitely check out the docs on this.

Comment: MySQL will try to make some best guess efforts if you insert data in a non-compliant format like `YYYY/MM/DD,HH:MM:SS` from your example. In your case it handles the `/` but blew up on the `,` so it didn't try to handle the time component.  Stick with `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, `NOW()`, or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for accurate results.

Comment: OK, that should do it.  I appreciate everything.

Comment: @user1799250 No problem. At least you have likely learned the lesson that data and datetime fields are best for this data :)  Most people learn this via first trying to use unix timestamp values and then run into the limitations there.

Answer (score 3):

You really should use MySQL's [temporal types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-types.html) for storing temporal data:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ADD COLUMN new_time DATETIME AFTER time;

UPDATE my_table SET new_time = STR_TO_DATE(time, '%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s');

ALTER TABLE my_table
  DROP time,
  CHANGE new_time time DATETIME;
```

Beware that you will need to alter your application code to use the new data format too.

If you are unable to change the column data type, you can `ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE()` in the interim (but it will not be very performant).

Comment: I know.  I'm not looking forward to changing the code to utilize the new data format, LOL..  I appreciate the prompt response !  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your select you can use:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2012-10-10', '%y/%c/%d');
```

to change it to the format you want. Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format for further details.